# What is the connection between a complete set of reduced residues modulo n and the number of primitive roots to n?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

Hi I am trying to understand the proofs regarding number of primitive roots. I have tried many sources, but they all start basically the same without any justification. Maybe it is just me who is not smart enough...

The theorem goes like this: "If $n$ has a primitive root, then it has exactly $\phi(\phi(n))$ incongruent primitive roots."

The first line of the proof is "If $a$ is a primitive root of $n$, then all primitive roots of $n$ must be of the form $a^k$ where $1 \leq k \leq \phi(n)$ according to theorem X.X", where theorem X.X is stating that the set $\lbrace a, a^2, \ldots , a^{\phi(n)} \rbrace $ is a complete set of reduced residues modulo $n$ when $a$ is a primitive root to $n$.

**I do understand that** $\lbrace a, a^2, \ldots , a^{\phi(n)} \rbrace $ is a complete set of reduced residues modulo $n$ when $a$ is a primitive root to $n$. **But I do not understand what this has to do with** the claim that any primitive root to $n$ must be of the form $a^k$ where $1 \leq k \leq \phi(n)$. **I just can't see the connection, what am I missing?**

Thanks in advance

Comment: *All* residue classes prime to $n$ must have the form $a^k$ for $1≤k≤\varphi(n)$.  That's what a primitive root means.

Comment: I don't even know what a "residue classes prime to n" means.
All I know is that a primitive root a to n is relatively prime to n and that its order is phi(n) modulo n. In other words, the lowest exponent k of a that makes a^k congruent to 1 modulo n is k = phi(n).

Comment: Do you know what a residue class is?  Do you know what "prime to $n$" means?

Comment: Say $n=12$.  A complete set of residues prime to $n$ would then be $\{1,5,7,11\}$ since every integer prime to $12$ is congruent to one of those four $\pmod {12}$.

Comment: You said you understood that the set of distinct powers of a primitive root covers all the residues relatively prime to $n$, right?  Any other primitive root would have to be a residue relatively prime to $n$ so such a primitive root would have to appear in the set of powers of the first one.

Comment: Ok, so when you write "prime to" you actually mean "relatively prime to"?

Comment: Those two phrases mean the same thing, so yes.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) for a discussion of the various terminologies and notations used to describe coprime integers.

Comment: Ok but what I if I do this example. Let $n = 9$. I know that $a=2$ is a primitive root to 9 because $\phi(9) = 6 = k$ is the smallest exponent that makes $2^k$ congruent to 1 modulo $n$. Another primitive root to 9 is 5. But 5 is not of the form $2^m$. However, there is a power of 2 that is congruent to 5 modulo 9.  And that power of 2, namely $2^m$, is in the set of residues relatively prime to n, hence $ 1 \leq m \leq \phi(n)$.  

Is this how to think about it by using a concrete example?

Comment: Of course $5$ is of the form $2^a\pmod 9$.  You just need to solve $2^a\equiv 5\pmod 9$ and we quickly see that $a=5$ is a solution (since $2^5=32\equiv 5 \pmod 9$).

Comment: I guess my problem was that I forgot to calculate in modulo n. Thanks for all help

Comment: I want to clarify that the condition for $a^k$ to be a primitive root modulo $n$ is that $1 \leq k \leq \phi(n)$ **and** $\text{gcd}(k,\phi(n)=1$. (This explains why there are $\phi(\phi(n))$ primitive roots modulo $n$).